# How do you keep pyspark from duplicating data with explode()?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

```
[{
        "Data": [{
                "Customer": [{
                        "Prices": {
                            "USD": [[86, "2.18"], [172, "1.67"], [344, "1.52"]]
                        },
                        "Seller": {
                            "Name": "Customer1"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "Prices": {
                            "USD": [[1, "1.99"], [100, "1.55"], [500, "1.24"]]
                        },
                        "Seller": {
                            "Name": "Customer2"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "PartNumber": "ABC"
    }
]
```

Using the above json, I am trying to create a table that shows a row for each customer and their unique price breaks.

```
df1 = dfJsonFile.withColumn("Customer", explode("Data.Customer"))

df2 = df1.select("*").withColumn("PriceArray", explode("Customer.Prices.USD")
                    ).withColumn("PriceBreaks", explode("PriceArray"))

df3 = df2.withColumn("Quantity", col("PriceBreaks").getItem(0)
        ).withColumn("Price", col("PriceBreaks").getItem(1))

df4 = df3.select("Customer.Seller.Name", "PartNumber", "Quantity", "Price")
+----------------------+----------+--------+-----+
|Name                  |PartNumber|Quantity|Price|
+----------------------+----------+--------+-----+
|[Customer1, Customer2]|ABC       |86      |2.18 |
|[Customer1, Customer2]|ABC       |172     |1.67 |
|[Customer1, Customer2]|ABC       |344     |1.52 |
|[Customer1, Customer2]|ABC       |1       |1.99 |
|[Customer1, Customer2]|ABC       |100     |1.55 |
|[Customer1, Customer2]|ABC       |500     |1.24 |
+----------------------+----------+--------+-----+
```

I need to get the customer parsed out so if I explode Customer I get duplicate (incorrect) results:

```
df5 = df4.withColumn("Customer", explode("Name"))

df5.select("Customer", "PartNumber", "Quantity", "Price").show()
+---------+----------+--------+-----+
| Customer|PartNumber|Quantity|Price|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+
|Customer1|       ABC|      86| 2.18|
|Customer2|       ABC|      86| 2.18|
|Customer1|       ABC|     172| 1.67|
|Customer2|       ABC|     172| 1.67|
|Customer1|       ABC|     344| 1.52|
|Customer2|       ABC|     344| 1.52|
|Customer1|       ABC|       1| 1.99|
|Customer2|       ABC|       1| 1.99|
|Customer1|       ABC|     100| 1.55|
|Customer2|       ABC|     100| 1.55|
|Customer1|       ABC|     500| 1.24|
|Customer2|       ABC|     500| 1.24|
+---------+----------+--------+-----+
```

What am I doing wrong?  These are the results I'm trying to return:

```
Customer    Quantity    Price
Customer1   86          2.18
Customer1   172         1.67
Customer1   344         1.52
Customer2   1           1.99
Customer2   100         1.55
Customer2   500         1.24
```

Comment: `df1 = dfJsonFile.withColumn("Customer", explode("Data.Customer"))` causes your problems because it assigns each price to both customers

Comment: How can I get to the prices without exploding Customer?

Comment: The above comment isn't right, it's the subesequent code statements that cause the duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding columns using explode, whereas you want to select the columns you don't want to duplicate and then explode those that you do, like so:

```
df1 = dfJsonFile.withColumn("Customer", explode("Data.Customer"))
df2 = df1.select(explode("Customer")).select("col.*")
df3 = df2.select(col("Seller.Name").alias("name"), explode("Prices.USD"))
+---------+-----------+
|     name|        col|
+---------+-----------+
|Customer1| [86, 2.18]|
|Customer1|[172, 1.67]|
|Customer1|[344, 1.52]|
|Customer2|  [1, 1.99]|
|Customer2|[100, 1.55]|
|Customer2|[500, 1.24]|
+---------+-----------+
```

I believe you know how to finish this off :-)